# regex not matched

Tags: java, regex, spring

I have this expression to match in order to find the right file

```js
(123456A)(.*?)(?:\\")' 'parts'}}{{parts.0}}{{parts.1}}
```

It does not match with `123456A000000022`

Comment: The first capture group is missing `0`

Comment: `(123456A).0*2*` isn't this works with your provided string, also `(.*?)` this will stop to see the further stuff in your regex.

Comment: Try any site like https://regexr.com/ to help you build the regex you want.

Comment: Can you add to the question how you are using that in code? If that by itself is a regex, it does not match the example string as there are no curly brackets or `parts`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the HTML nature of posting here has hidden some of your potential match string from us, but it clearly won't match.

This is a great tool for building complex regex strings and testing them:  https://regex101.com/

From what I see, the non-capturing group requires the string to have a backslash, so the match fails right there.  I don't understand the rest of what you were intending with your match string, because there are mismatched quotes and braces.  Again, I suspect I'm not seeing what you actually intended.